# Configurar pré-fixo url da aplicação com Tomcat

Tags: vue.js, apache, tomcat

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em Vue, gerei a pasta **dist** para produção e consegui publica-lá usando o Tomcat. No caso joguei a pasta dist gerada na pasta /webapps/helloWorld.

Consigo acessar pelo link

```
http://localhost:8080/helloWorld
```

até ai tudo bem. O problema é que o

`/helloWorld`

só funciona para o primeiro acesso, ele não fica como pre-fixo do link. É tanto que após o primeiro acesso o link fica assim:

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

Caso eu queira ir para tela de **home** era pra eu digitar

```
http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/home
```

Porém isso não funciona, só funciona assim:

```
http://localhost:8080/home
```

Como faço para deixar o /helloWorld/ como pré-fixo em todas as rotas?

Answer (score 2):

Seria interessante você hospedar o seu código ou as configurações das suas rotas para a gente conseguir entender melhor o que pode estar acontecendo, mas isso provavelmente está acontecendo devido às rotas estarem fazendo parte do mesmo "nivel" de hierarquia, verifique se a rota "home" está sendo declarada dentro de um children da "helloworld". Ficaria algo semelhante a isso:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/helloworld', component: HelloWorld,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'home',
          component: Home
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Exemplo oficial do Vue.js no CodePen:
https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/

Fonte:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html